# How to continuously check internet connection on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I want to implement an internet connection checker in my app using an isolate! I want this to be a background task (not on the same thread as the main app). How should I implement this? I already created the code of the internet connection checker, but i don't really know where i should create the isolate and how should i link it to the internet connection checker.

Comment: To get a faster response,
 Please follow the stackoverflow guidelines and provide debug details (eg. copy the internet connection checker code here).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package [Connectivity Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)

and here some example

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> connectivityPlus;
      
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    connectivityPlus = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (ConnectivityResult.none == result) {
        Helper(ctx: context).showAlertDialog(
          context: context,
          icon: Icons.wifi_off_rounded,
          text: 'Please check your internet connection',
          titleLeft: 'Close',
          oneButton: true,
        );
      } else if (ConnectivityResult.mobile == result) {
      } else if (ConnectivityResult.wifi == result) {}
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    connectivityPlus.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I am also using Connectivity Plus, but i would love to do the connection checking outside the Main app, create an isolate, i don't know if you have an idea on how i should do it